# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() when submit form

Tags: laravel

I want to submit multiple form using `foreach` in controller.

```
  public function checkout(Request $request){
    $title = $request->title;
    $f_name = $request->f_name;
    $l_name = $request->l_name;
    $fullname = $title.' '.$f_name.' '.$l_name;
    $data=[];
    foreach ($fullname as $key => $value) {
      $data[] = [
        "name" => $value,
        "email" => $request->email[$key],
        "phone" => $request->phone[$key],
        "position" => $request->position[$key],
        "category" => $request->category[$key],
        "price" => $request->price[$key],
        "company" => $request->company[$key],
        "payment_id" => $request->payment_id[$key]
      ];
    }
    //return $data;
    Conference::insert($data);
    //Mail::to('indoebtkeconex@dyandra.com')->send(new ConferenceMail($data));
    return redirect('form/conference-registration');
    //return view('detail')->with('data',$data);
  }
```

but it return error like this
[image: the error]

what do i do wrong, and what the solution for this?

Comment: `$fullname` is not an `array` its just a string data. Solution for this will you need tell what you are using `foreach` for and what are trying to do ?

Comment: so i have to change it to an array? how to change it?

Comment: what you are using `foreach` for and what are trying to do ? How the `$requests` looks like. Post a var_dump of `$request`

Comment: I doubt if you need for-each at all there. I think you do not need it.

Comment: Please provide the form you want to submit.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know why you foreach "$fullname".

Currently `$fullname` is combination of `title` , `f_name`  and `l_name`  with data type is `string` but first argument of foreach should be array|object given.

What's wrong here?

Comment: A answer is typically not for asking further questions. Please use comments instead.

Comment: coz have question "what do i do wrong?". so i explain that the syntax is error. Thank you